# Request external storage permission without using packages flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I need to request permission from the user to grant access to a repository without using the permission_handler package or others in flutter. I have error after run app.
Unhandled Exception: PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = '/sdcard/Download/events.json' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Comment: You can achieve it by diving directly into the native language (kotlin/java for Android, Swift/Obj C for iOS). When you create a Flutter project, there is an android folder and an ios folder (or any). But I think that to complex and spending a time. So use a [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) is better way

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.